# Add additional text to an existing string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, hyperlink

I have a SQL table with a column named "FileLink" and I need to add the domain name at the end of the server name for all the existing records in the table. So it would be like this:

Before:
\\ServerName\SharedFolder\Test.PDF

After: 
\\ServerName.domain.net\SharedFolder\Test.PDF

So I need to add ".domain.net" to the link. Is there a sql statement to do this?

TIA

Comment: No function, just the `+` concatenation operator: `update yourtable set foo=foo+'bar'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to modify only one domain and this value is unique you can use REPLACE:

```
update Table
set Column = REPLACE(Column, 'ServerName', 'ServerName.domain.net')
```

Comment: Hopefully the file name and/or foldername don't have the same name as the "serverName" though..

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use the replace statement you can do it like this:

```
Declare 
        @SrvName as varchar(50)

Set @SrvName = '\\ServerName'

Select 
    '\\ServerName.domain.net'+Substring(FileLink,Len(@SrvName)+1,Len(FileLink)-Len(@SrvName))
```

Answer (score 1):

If the servername is the same for each record you could do it with the replace statement. Otherwise you might want to use patindex to find the first occurence of a '\' starting from position 3 to determin the place you need to insert the extra text.

Comment: Thank you, yes it is the same server name. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prevent any issue if you run the query against old and new records, you should use

```
REPLACE(FileLink, '\\ServerName\', '\\ServerName.domain.net\')
```

Which gives:

**SELECT**

```
SELECT REPLACE(FileLink, '\\ServerName\', '\\ServerName.domain.net\') AS FileLinkUpdated
FROM MyTable
```

**UPDATE**

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FileLink = REPLACE(FileLink, '\\ServerName\', '\\ServerName.domain.net\')
```

Note that this is assuming you don't have a link with only `\\ServerName`